# What should I change in my code to sort city names, but it has non english letters too?

Tags: java

Code works. It sorts from A to Z. But there are Ç, İ etc. They come after Z which is wrong.

Here is the code

KeyValueDTO.java

```
public class KeyValueDTO implements Comparable<KeyValueDTO> {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "KeyValueDTO [key=" + key + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(KeyValueDTO other) {
        return key.compareTo(other.key);
    }
    
    /*
    public int compare(KeyValueDTO s1, KeyValueDTO s2) {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr", "TR"));
        return collator.compare(s1, s2);
    }*/
    
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCities", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Cacheable("cities")
    public @ResponseBody List<KeyValueDTO> getCities() {
        logger.trace("getCities begins.");
        List<City> cityList = cityService.findAll();
        List<KeyValueDTO> cityKeyDtoList = new ArrayList<KeyValueDTO>();
        

        for (City city : cityList) {
            KeyValueDTO cityKeyDto = new KeyValueDTO();
            cityKeyDto.setKey(city.getName());
            cityKeyDto.setValue(String.valueOf(city.getCode()));
            cityKeyDtoList.add(cityKeyDto);
            
        }
        Collections.sort(cityKeyDtoList);
        // Collections.sort(cityKeyDtoList,Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr", "TR")));

        logger.trace("CityController: getAllCities ends");
        return cityKeyDtoList;
    }
```

it works from A to Z, but not Ç İ.. I tried to add `Collactor` i couldnt use it right way. Could u do some help please?

I wrote this but it doesnt work. It stops running on eclipse.

```
public @ResponseBody List<KeyValueDTO> getCities() {
        logger.trace("getCities begins.");
        List<City> cityList = cityService.findAll();
        List<KeyValueDTO> cityKeyDtoList = new ArrayList<KeyValueDTO>();
        
        Locale turkish = new Locale("tr", "TR");
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(turkish);
        
        for (City city : cityList) {
            KeyValueDTO cityKeyDto = new KeyValueDTO();
            cityKeyDto.setKey(city.getName());
            cityKeyDto.setValue(String.valueOf(city.getCode()));
            cityKeyDtoList.add(cityKeyDto);
            
        }
        //Collections.sort(cityKeyDtoList);
        // Collections.sort(cityKeyDtoList,Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr", "TR")));
        Collections.sort(cityKeyDtoList, collator);


        logger.trace("CityController: getAllCities ends");
        return cityKeyDtoList;
    }
```

Comment: Hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/41215909/4995907

Comment: thank you @RahulAgrawal im now trying what other friend suggested me, if it doesnt work, ill try what you sent me

Comment: try to use Collator and then sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have Ç and İ in your data. Let's assume it is Turkish.

```java
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Locale;

Locale turkish = new Locale("tr", "TR");
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(turkish);
Collections.sort(cityKeyDtoList, collator)
```

[image]

Example outcome is given above. Don't mind the class name, non-relevant.

---

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

Changed from `Comparable` to `Comparator`.

```java
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Locale;

public class KeyValueDTO{
    private String key;
    private String value;

    
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "KeyValueDTO [key=" + key + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }
    
    public Comparator<KeyValueDTO> comparisonOrder() {
        return new CustomComparator();
    }
    private class CustomComparator implements Comparator<KeyValueDTO> {

        @Override
        public int compare(KeyValueDTO o1, KeyValueDTO o2) {
            Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr", "TR"));
            return collator.compare(o1.getKey(), o2.getKey());
        }
        
    }

}
```

example main:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        KeyValueDTO city1= new KeyValueDTO();
        city1.setKey("Adana");
        KeyValueDTO city2= new KeyValueDTO();
        city2.setKey("İstanbul");
        KeyValueDTO city3= new KeyValueDTO();
        city3.setKey("Zonguldak");
        KeyValueDTO city4= new KeyValueDTO();
        city4.setKey("Çanakkale");
        
        List<KeyValueDTO> cityKeyDtoList = new ArrayList<KeyValueDTO>();
        cityKeyDtoList.add(city1);
        cityKeyDtoList.add(city2);
        cityKeyDtoList.add(city3);
        cityKeyDtoList.add(city4);
        
        
        Collections.sort(cityKeyDtoList, city1.comparisonOrder());
        System.out.println(cityKeyDtoList.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you look at my edit please? i updated `the controller` but it didnt work out

Comment: What kind of an error do you get? Can you share it?

Comment: Says `Unable to create requested service` also on developer tools when i  request, it shows `Failed` in `network-status` The codes in my question were working before i made changes. I dont know maybe i added your code into wrong place? but idk where and how to correct it

Comment: i found this https://ofarukkurt.blogspot.com/2016/12/collections-sort-turkish-character.html but couldnt adjust it into my code either

Comment: I made some search about your errors, but they don't seem to be related to the code itself. Rather they seem to be related with the database or something. Are you sure that those errors have occurred when you add the code part related to the ```collator```?

Comment: thanks.. But  i cant get the same result.. These things seem so confusing for me, and im expected to do this.. i just did sort from A to Z, it worked. but Ç İ and stuff,  i am stucked

Comment: yes, if u want i can delete and show you what i am getting. I mean it was working, It shows cities from A to Z, then like Çorum, İstanbul İzmir etc. But after I edit `Controller` it stopped working.

Comment: For now, comment the sorting section. Just add the ```locale```, do not add the ```collator``` part. If it doesn't give any error, add the ```collator``` part. If also it doesn't give any error, add the ```Collection.sort``` part. Let's try to find which one causes that error.

Comment: I commented all 3 lines, and added this `Collections.sort(cityKeyDtoList);` it works from A to Z. Now as u said, i only commented out `locale` after commenting  `Collections.sort(cityKeyDtoList);`  it has no problem. now commenting out `collator` too

Comment: when i comment out last part `Collections.sort(cityKeyDtoList, collator);` gives `"Internal Server Error",`

Comment: Can you try the alternative solution? You should modify your KeyValueDTO class. It should use Comparator rather than Comparable.

Comment: in DTO i added `public int compare(KeyValueDTO s1,KeyValueDTO s2){
         Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr", "TR"));
         return collator.compare(s1, s2);
     }` and implemented Comparator instead of Comparable, but same error..

Comment: ```return collator.compare(o1.getKey(), o2.getKey());```, you have to compare the keys. collator doesn't accept an object rather than a string, that's why you get the error. Copy paste the code I gave above for DTO. And call ```Collections.sort(cityKeyDtoList, cityKeyDtoList.get(0).comparisonOrder());``` in your Controller. It must work.

Comment: it wanted me to  add comparisonOrder() method which i didnt have exist... Btw i added this in Controller `Comparator<KeyValueDTO> compTr = new Comparator<KeyValueDTO>(){
         @Override
         public int compare(KeyValueDTO s1, KeyValueDTO s2) {
          Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr" ,"TR"));
          return collator.compare(s1.getKey(), s2.getKey());
         }
        };
        Collections.sort(cityKeyDtoList,compTr);` it works now

Comment: I'm very happy that the problem is solved. Error was due to the fact that we tried to use collator for DTO objects rather than DTO keys (string). Overriding ```compare``` method should've solved the problem and yes it did. You can override the ```compare``` method in your Controller or in your DTO class. I preferred doing it in the DTO because I believe it's a nice practice, and you can use that ```CustomComparator``` whenever you want in your project.

Comment: You are awesome, thank you  a lot.. I wish we could chat sometime, i can guess you are much younger than me, but i can learn many from you,

Comment: is there any chance to chat with you? id like to ask u some questions towards software world, and computer engineering etc

Comment: I tried to open a chat room or something like that on Stackoverflow but I can't invite you, I think you must have at least 20 reputation. Do you have Reddit? If you provide your username, I can write to you.

Comment: thanks, thats my profile https://www.reddit.com/user/semih_here  semih_here is my username, id like to chat when u get free

Comment: can u look at my newly asked question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68612344/how-can-i-show-or-hide-rows-depending-on-a-value-in-selectbox