# How can I show or hide rows depending on a value in selectbox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one `SelectBox`, it can have values as `1,2,3`.

Lets say This selectbox's name is : `selectbox1`.

There are `3 rows`.

1.row => There is selectBox named `selectbox2`, and textbox named `textbox1`

2.row => There is selectBox named `selectbox3`, and textbox named `textbox2`

3.row => There is selectBox named `selectbox4`, and textbox named `textbox3`

If the value in selextBox1 equal to 1, only 1.row will be shown which are selextbox2, and textbox1

I can get the value in selectbox1 by this code,

```
var source = document.getElementsByName("selectbox1")[0].value;
```

But i couldnt make the rows show and hide based on the output of selextbox1

What function to write to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="vals">Choose</label>
  <select name="vals" id="vals" onchange="updateDisplay(this.value)">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>

  <div id='row1'>
    <p>this is row 1</p>  
  </div>

  <div id='row2' style="display:none;">
    <p>this is row 2</p>  
  </div>
  
  <div id='row3' style="display:none;">
    <p>this is row 3</p>  
  </div>

<script>
const updateDisplay = (rowNumber) => {
    for(let i=1;i<4;i++) $(`#row${i}`).hide(); // hide all rows
    $(`#row${rowNumber}`).show();// show the required row
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have used jQuery's hide and show function to make the code look simpler. The same can be implemented using vanilla JavaScript as well like:

HIDE -> document.getElementById("row2").style.display = 'none';

SHOW -> document.getElementById("row2").style.display = 'block';

Comment: thank you for the answer. How to update this code? I mean if its 1 , i want to show only one row, but if its 2, i want to show first 2 rows

Comment: You can do something like say n=2 and we want to show first 2 rows, then -> for(let i=1;i<n+1;i++) $(`#row${i}`).show();

Comment: i did same by using selext box name and text box name . but  i get reference error, it says none is not defined.. What can i do?

Comment: i guess style.display property only works for id, but not name

Comment: getElementsByName returns an array of elements and we need to use indexing to access each element in the array. Also, make sure the name that you are searching for is correct. This might be a reason for your reference error, not sure though. Also, try switching to id as name is deprecated.